Software for calculation of polyhedral packing fractions of crystal structures?
I know how to calculate the polyhedral packing fraction of simple crystal structures, but in a lot cases, the structure is not cubic and the polyhedra are irregular, and it becomes very tedious to calculate the polyhedral packing fractions by hand. I am wondering if anyone knows of any software that can calculate the polyhedral packing fractions based on an input structure file(i.e., a .cif file)?
For example, for some common oxides: NiO consists of densely packed octahedra, while ZnO consists of tetrahedra connected only by point-sharing (not densely packed). The polyhedral packing fraction of the former is much higher than that of the latter:


ADDENDUM for non crystallographers:


I can get results from google looking for 'packing fraction' but no hits for'polyhedral packing fraction'

Same, which I find quite odd given that the concept's easily derivative of the typical 'atomic packing fraction'.

WIKIPERDIA Packing fraction may refer to:
Packing density, the fraction of the space filled by objects comprising the packing
Atomic packing factor, the fraction of volume in a crystal structure that is occupied by the constituent particles
Packing fraction (mass spectrometry), the atomic mass defect per nucleon


now I guess its either the space not filled is made of polyhedrals or we are talking about empty space of polyhedral crystalline matter

please clarify what kind of : input structure file? or better add an example

"empty space of polyhedral crystalline matter" is more like what I'm referring to (See edited post).

Can any one help me to calculate packing coefficient from crystal structure or from cif file?

Platon ??   VOID & SOLV Calculations ??

These seem to be for the atomic packing factor, although similar methods are preferred for the polyhedral one of interest.

So with polyhedral you dont mean the shape of the crystals base unit  but that you want to evaluate only the volume occupied by your depicted gray volume without taking into account the entire VdW radii of the red atoms ??

Please use one of the chat rooms if you need to discuss further in comments.
